Why did deportation of illegal immigrants drop so much under Biden, compared to Obama?
(The Economist Jan 2024) America’s border crisis in ten charts
I found this below to be a striking graphic, but I don't really remember any high level policy proposals stating that deportations of illegal immigrants was to be lowered that much.
I understand that there was a desire to reverse many of Trump's policies, but this is why this question is instead comparing it to Obama's policies.  Obama was nicknamed the Deporter in Chief by some, but Obama's enduring popularity with Democrats also means that some levels of coercive enforcement are clearly acceptable to the public:

The enforcement priorities and policies, which evolved over the years, represented a significant departure from those of the Bush and Clinton administrations. As detailed below, the Obama-era policies represented the culmination of a gradual but consistent effort to narrow its enforcement focus to two key groups: The deportation of criminals and recent unauthorized border crossers.

In an election year, it seems clear that Biden's record on immigration and border control is eliciting concerns, even from Democrats

Moderate Democrats also support imposing greater penalties on businesses that hire without legal work authorization (68% vs. 40% liberals), increasing deportations (64% vs. 37%), and expanding the border wall and fence along the US-Mexico border (56% vs. 15%).

What drove this deportation policy change, compared to pre-Trump times?

FWIW Title 42 immigration restrictions - using a 1944 law allowing limits at border crossings for public health reasons - ran from March 2020 to May 2023

What happened in 2020 that stopped everyone from traveling, illegally or not, I wonder... Funny how people have already forgotten all about it 4 years later.

@Lundin I encourage you to write an answer on that basis then.  Personally, I feel kinda sheepish but did not make the connection, mostly as I was quite surprised by the drop's magnitude.  The top voted answer is good, but IMHO unnecessarily stresses other points than covid which kinda dilutes its clarity.

Part of the explanation may be that Democratic deportation policy may follow the actual degree of undocumented immigration to the USA, presumably with a bit of a lag for policy to catch up with border crossings. This would contrast with Republicans, who often have anti-immigration policies as a core part of their campaigns, particularly with Trump.
This would make particular sense in conjunction with the dramatic drop in immigration during the first year of the COVID-19 pandemic.
Consider the following graph from Pew:

Undocumented immigration was high during the Bush years, but steadily declining when Obama took office. And deportation during that term followed the same trend: it was high, yes, but can clearly be seen to be decreasing, leveling out around 2015 or 2016—just as immigration had leveled out a few years before.
During the Trump administration, given his aggressive anti-immigrant rhetoric, we could expect yearly deportations to increase from the level that they had been at the end of Obama's term, regardless of trends in immigration, and that is what happened, according to the bar chart in the question. Though not as much as some might have predicted, perhaps suggesting more influence from lower-level employees, Trump's lack of interest in pairing rhetoric with action, or both.
The level of deportations started low during the first year of the Biden administration, probably because crossings had been low a few years previously, during all of Obama's term and most of Trump's. In particular, Trump had closed the borders during the COVID-19 pandemic, which led to an extremely low level of both legal and illegal immigration when Biden took office. But deportations have been increasing, as that bar chart clearly shows, presumably shadowing the increase in border crossings.

Another possible explanation is that Democrats simply have less of an appetite for deportations than they did a decade ago.
Data from Gallup polling suggests a potential 20 to 30 point rise in support for increased immigration in general among Democrats since the middle of the Obama presidency.

While immigration and undocumented immigration are not the same, it seems possible that sympathy toward undocumented immigrants and opposition to deportations has followed a similar trend.
As to why that might be, individuals within the Democratic Party have become more liberal and those within the Republican Party more conservative to a substantial degree. It's not simply a question of society as a whole adopting more progressive social views, either; the Republican Party has actually become more conservative in some respects. There has also been a degree of sorting, with individuals leaving one party and joining others that fit them better, something that is even reflected among politicians.

I'm pretty sure the support for immigration is for legal immigration, and not sympathy toward illegal immigration although the other points in this answer are correct.

@whoisit: I don’t think many Americans support illegal immigration, but I do think people who are more positive about legal immigration are typically less strongly against illegal migration, more sympathetic to the situation of illegal migrants, and less likely to support harsh crackdowns.

You're right, covid probably explains a good deal of it (and maybe the answer should put more focus on that if you feel it warranted).  Title 42 - "stay out, health emergency!" ran from March 2020 to May 2023.  You can see the numbers' trend from Trump 2019, Trump 2020 to Biden 2021.  And then it rises back up @ Biden 2023.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: legal immigrants are generally all in on legal Immigration, but but totally against illegal immigration…

Given the devastation, corruption and oppression in most of Central and South America, it is quite reasonable to argue that most irregular crossings into the USA from its land border with Mexico are refugees, which the USA is required under its freely entered international treaty obligations to shelter.  Hence "undocumented immigrant".  The use of "illegal" for undocumented immigrants is both intentionally dehumanizing and violates the principle of innocent until proven guilty.  In fact, it is quite likely the USA is illegally deporting millions of legitimate refugees.

@Yakk - Sorry, is this directed at me? The answer in fact primarily talks about "undocumented immigration," because I do consider it more precise. Not that I necessarily object to the term "illegal immigration," either, though "illegal" is clearly simply an insult and "illegal immigrant" is too easily interpreted as ascribing legality to a person rather than an action.

As for the argument that the international treaties that the USA (and other countries) have ratified require them to treat most immigrants from Central America and South America as refugees, it is a potential argument. On the face of it, the Convention on the Status of Refugees, which the USA did not ratify but did accept through the Protocal Relating to the Status of Refugees, does not establish a broad enough definition to cover most immigrants. But it does reference several other conventions as providing supplementary definitions; perhaps one of those could provide a basis.
